# how scroll listview to a position assigned by programe smoothly?

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

Here i make a listview with sectionHeader, and then i supply a sub navigator for quick navigation, just like the contact list ,,the question is :

The listview has 3000 rows, when first come to the view, i click 'z' to quickly navigate to bottom of listview,,but i had to wait for the all the section redered.

Any some best ways to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Which programming language are you using? And it'll be easier to help you if you post your code.

Comment: react native for ios